# Database file is missing when pushing my code in Source tree

Tags: database, model-view-controller, atlassian-sourcetree

I have my database file in`"~/App_Data/Database1.mdf`".When I push my project files through source tree It is working fine.One of my friend pull that code for project he couldn't find my database file.
It is empty.Help me to solve this issue

Comment: Check if you have the mdf extension added in .gitignore file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copied a generic .gitignore file from internet, ensure the line .mdf is removed. 
Since you're using SourceTree, choose 'Show Ignored' in working copy to see the list of files ignored